# Is an ASP.NET Webform control analogous to a JavaServer Faces component?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, jsf-2.2

I'm having trouble seeing the difference between the two.  They seem the same.  Other than one is Oracle and one is Microsoft, are they they same concept?  When I look at creating an ASP.NET Webform control, however, it looks like a different process, more like a webpage that can be rendered as a widget.  The JSF component looked a little more complicated to create.

Comment: You may be looking at user controls, which are sort of like mini-pages. "Custom", or "Server" controls are purely code, with no markup. Also, why the comparison? Were you planning to use JSF with ASP.NET pages?

Comment: @JohnSaunders No, I want to use JSF, and it reminded me of ASP.NET Webforms.  JavaEE went from MVC to Component based, and Microsoft went from component/Webform based to MVC.

Comment: FYI, Microsoft didn't go "from web forms to MVC". MVC stands _beside_ web forms, but does not replace it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't mean it replaced Webforms, but it does seem that Webforms, while still supported (as Classic ASP is), and useful depending on the project, is not touted as much as it used to be ten years ago.

Comment: "touting" is a marketing issue, not a technical one.

Comment: @JohnSaunders sounds better for a chat.  But I am hoping someone can answer my concerns.

Comment: Well, I don't know about JSF, so can't help you there. I just hate reading misinformation.

Answer (score 3):

This question is quite old. But I know as technology evolves there's many other people confused on the subject like I was when I began my coding career years back.

Having spent my past 5 years doing JSF prior to switching to ASP.NET due to its "Core" version being an open-source. The concepts behind JSF and Webforms is the same.

It doesn't really matter how the other does it, that's just style, but the concept is the same. It's as simple as putting Widgets/components on a page and each widget/component can have its own model and persist its own data if you wish to, or data can be communicated from the parent component.

I believe component based programming is very useful when building enterprise applications . I do not blame JEE developers for introducing JSF. It's really useful when building complex Enterprise Apps, not simple websites that a lot of developers use these tools for and deem them to be useless. Like Desktop Apps, JSF and WebForms were created to give the developer an ease to apply the same approach they use when building Desktop Applications.